# RSAEncryptionPadding could not be found

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, padding, monodevelop

I have been trying to change the padding and hashing mode of the encryption function in C#:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt132684(v=vs.110).aspx

I tried:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaAlg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider ();
byte[] encrypted = rsaAlg.Encrypt (
                      System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes (msg),
                      RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
```

An error occurred during compilation saying : The type or namespace name RSAEncryptionPadding could not be found.

What should I do to change the padding?

Comment: That is strange because that type should be in  (ms)corlib

Comment: It is really strange. The class did not even show up in the hints box as I type the class name, in both Visual Studio and Monodevelop.

Comment: Are you targeting .Net 4.6?

Comment: Well, it is .Net 4.6.